# Need to turn off JPA in SpringBoot app, get "At least one JPA metamodel must be present!"

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot

I'm working on a SpringBoot app that was generated from a rather complex template.  It's just a REST service that will access a db through a datasource.  It doesn't use JPA.

When my app starts up, I see the following output (which is likely almost identical to other questions similar to this):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaMetamodelMappingContext.<init>(JpaMetamodelMappingContext.java:52)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:26)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

I've already read most of the reports of the other occurrences of this, and I checked with someone else on my team who ran into the same problem, and I believe I have the correct fix, but it's still not working.

The following is my Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com")
//@EnableAsync
//@EnableCaching
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
                                     HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
                                     HazelcastAutoConfiguration.class,
                                     CacheAutoConfiguration.class,
                                     JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class })
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(Application.class, AppConfig.class).run(args);
    }
}
```

In the application pom, I'm specifying "spring-boot-starter-web" as a dependency.

What else could be wrong here?

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: Sigh.  It's 600 lines long (again, from a template).  I'll update with an elided version.

Comment: Before I do that, are there particular transitive dependencies that I should be looking for that might be causing this?  The template uses a company "starter" pom that includes a lot of things. For instance, it includes the hibernate jpa artifact and other similar things.

Comment: Have you removed any spring JPA references from your pom? I'm not sure what the error is but might help someone spot the problem.

Comment: I don't have any JPA artifacts directly in the POM, but the internal "starter" pom includes many transitive dependencies. It ends up including "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa".  I tried adding an exclusion for that, but that removes "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate". So I then added "spring-jdbc" directly, but that fails with "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No supported DataSource type found".

Comment: Ok. I think I may have resolved this. I excluded "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa", but included "spring-boot-starter-jdbc". That appears to only include the elements I need, and I don't get the JPA error.